# Silverlight - Binding with ObservableCollections

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

This is no doubt a newbish question, but I have looked for an answer to no avail.  My setup is simple: I have a ListBox control defined in XAML and an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` in the same class.  I am binding the `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` to the ListBox.

Within the hierarchy of this ListBox in XAML, I want to bind to a given MyClass object, not to a child property of the MyClass object.

To clarify, I have XAML that looks like the following (I bind the ObservableCollection  in code):

```
  <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <MyControls:SpecialControl MyClassObj="{Binding !!!}" />
     </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Surely there is a way to get at the object of an ObservableCollection rather than being forced to bind to one of its child properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to specify a `Path` if you want to use the bound object itself:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <MyControls:SpecialControl MyClassObj="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

BTW: Instead of your custom property, you can use the `DataContext` property of your control to bind the control to the object:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <MyControls:SpecialControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks!  You seem to have read my mind in also suggesting I bind directly to DataContext.  That never occurred to me, but it is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As well as specifying the binding path in your XAML you have to bind your collection to the ListBox.

C#

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
MyListBox.DataContext = myCollection;
```

The XAML you have used won't be particularly useful unless you have overriden the ToString method on MyClass. Even though you say you're not are you sure it's not a property of MyClass that you want to bind to? I can't see why you'd want to bind directly to a collection object.

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">  
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
        <DataTemplate>      
            <MyControls:SpecialControl MyClassObj="{Binding Path=MyClassProperty}" />    
        </DataTemplate>  
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: The SpecialControl must bind properties of the object to some of its child elements.  Perhaps I am doing this impropertly, but I don't see a better method if I want the SpecialControl to be autonomous.

Comment: this does not make any sense to me.  How does MyClassProperty link the xaml to the c# code?