# Passing data to the listbox in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, listbox

Hai am creating a usercontol with two textblock and one listbox.
i can able to pass data to textblock in my usercontorl. but i cannot pass the data to my listbox in usercontrol. how to pass my data in the usercontrol

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TeamName
    {
        get { return textBlock1.Text; }
        set { textBlock1.Text = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CssRpt> CssDataList
    {
        get { return listBox1.ItemsSource; }
        set { listBox1.ItemsSource = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how to add data to a list box on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx) msdn tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try assigning into [`.DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480226.aspx)? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712398/silverlight-binding-with-observablecollections/712413#712413) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
YourListBox.DataSource = CssDataList
YourListBox.DisplayMember = "What u want to display"
```