# Binding Observable collection

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have a collection in the main window and I want to show it on a grid in a user Control,
What is the right MVVM way to do that ?

I've done an observableCollection in the MainWindow And bounded it to an observableCollection in the usercontrol. and in the user control the grid is bounded to 
the collection.

it doesn't work :(

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyNames
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(MyNamesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyNamesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Names.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyNamesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyNames", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyNames = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Jonh", "Mary" };
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

MainWindow XAML :

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
UseLayoutRounding="True"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Grid>
    <local:NamesControl Names="{Binding MyNames}"></local:NamesControl>
</Grid>
```

UserControl:

```
  public partial class NamesControl : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(NamesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NamesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Names.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NamesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Names", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(NamesControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    public NamesControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.NamesControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You might want to post a small example of the code.  There are many reasons this might not work.  Make sure you are setting the DataContext correctly.  Make sure your ItemsSource is bound correctly,etc.

Comment: Have you looked at this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712398/silverlight-binding-with-observablecollections

Comment: One red flag - you have a collection in the Main Window?  The "MVVM" way to do that is to have the collection in the ViewModel.

Comment: While I normally don't like design critiques as answers, I really suggest learning MVVM. The payoff is well worth the small learning curve. Check out MVVM Light if you haven't already: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/

Comment: Just a note: MVVM is an extension of MVC and (despite lots of code examples to the contrary) does not exclude the use of controllers. Your ViewModels are basically smart containers to hold data and properties the view requires. To be independently testable **it should not know where the data is coming from.** That is the job of a controller.

Answer (score 8):

The "right way" to do this is going to require three things:

- MainWindow
- UserControl
- ViewModel

In the ViewModel, you want to create your ObservableCollection and set it as a property on the ViewModel, like so:

```
public class MyListViewModel
{
  public MyViewModel()
  {
    MyObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
    // Add items to collection 
  }

  public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your UserControl's Initialize method you want to instantiate the ViewModel and attach it to the DataContext for that UserControl:

```
public AgentListView()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

Note: this is much easier if you're using an IoC container to handle dependency resolutions for you, but for simplicity sake I am skipping that here.

In your UserControl you want to specify the DataContext for the UserControl and then the individual Bindings for your DataGrid and the Columns:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControls.Views.AgentDataGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
             xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:UserControls.Utility"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{Binding}">
  <GroupBox Header="Agent States" Height="auto" Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="_groupBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue">
    <Grid Name="_grid" ShowGridLines="True" Margin="5" >
      <toolkit:DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects, Mode=OneWay}">
        <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
          <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StateAndJobDescription, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="State" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" />
          <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SubStateDescription, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="City" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
      </toolkit:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
  </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

From here, you just need to add the UserControl to your MainWindow.