# Load more items in listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I've read some topics/questions/google results before but still don't know how to solve my problem.

In my case I consume json and what I do is deserializing JSON into objects. Then using ListboxName.ItemsSource I bind them to listbox.

The problem is that my server gives me only 20 top results, but also I receive a link to next 20.

Theoretically, I would like to bind this link to LoadMore button which I would put at the end of the list. Then what? Merge new result to existing ObservableCollection? (I assume that I have to use ObservableCollection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an

```
ObservableCollection<Items> Items {get;set;}
```

then in XAML bind to it and add items to this collection. It will notify a list box to update a view.

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListboxName" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

in .cs file:

```
//After you have parsed json
private void OnNewDataDownloaded(List<Items> parsedItems)
{
   foreach(var item in parsedItems)
    {
       Items.Add(item);
    }

}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063268/listbox-with-load-more-option) you can find an elegant way to add LoadMore button

Comment: Thanks, that looks clean and nice but I have problem with JSON. I mean, I deserialize it into objects so I got some error with GetEnumerator in foreach statement. I guess that I have to change smth in my classes that I deserialise JSON into... do you know how I can handle it?

Comment: what type of collection do you get from deserializing you json? an array? a List? or you get items one by one?

Comment: I find the way to save it in ObservableCollection:
string commentsjsonstring = e.Result.ToString();
var parsedItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WP7SQLiteClient.JSONComments.RootObject>(commentsjsonstring);
                CommentItems = new ObservableCollection<WP7SQLiteClient.JSONComments.Object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < parsedItems.objects.Count(); ++i)
                {

                    CommentItems.Add(parsedItems.objects[i]);

                }
                CommentsListBox.ItemsSource = CommentItems;

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that I helped you :) you could try to use foreach(var item in parsedItems.objects) {Items.Add(item); } .